# Show that $f:X\to Y$ is an open mapping iff for all $A \subset Y, \, f^{-1}(A^\circ)\supset f^{-1}(A)^\circ$.

Tags: general-topology

Struggling with a proof from basic topology:

> Show that $f:X\to Y$ is an open mapping iff for all $A \subset Y, \,
>  f^{-1}(A^\circ)\supset f^{-1}(A)^\circ$.

I can show the $\implies$ direction as follows: Let $x\in f^{-1}(A)^\circ$. Then there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ and such that $U\subset f^{-1}(A)$, so $f(U)\subset A. \,\, f(U)$ is open since $f$ is open, so $f(U)\subset A^\circ$, so $x\in A^\circ.$

To show the $\impliedby$ direction, I'm struggling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U\subset X$ open, and $A = f(U)$. The condition directly yields $U \subset f^{-1}(A^\circ)$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have answered my own question:

Suppose $f^{-1}(A^\circ) \supset f^{-1}(A)^\circ$ for all $A\subset Y$, and let $U\subset X$ be open. We show that $f(U)^\circ = f(U)$, for which it suffices to show that $f(U)^\circ \supset f(U).$ Let $\beta \in f(U)$ and $U\ni \alpha \mapsto \beta.$ Now $f^{-1}(f(U)^\circ) \supset U^\circ = U$, so any $x\in U$ (in particular, $\alpha$), maps to some point in $f(U)^\circ$. So $\beta \in f(U)^\circ$.